# Invalid Cross Reference Key, can't access component

Tags: reference, invalid, key

I was working on my component, saving, testing, etc.

But then this happened:

[image]

I can still access to the controller and helper but not the component.

Below are two screenshots (can't post more than 2 links), the first one when I try to access the component from Eclipse, the second when I try from the setup part :
[image: Eclipse and Setup errors]

Comment: **[What is a gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I know what a gack is, but unfortunately it doesn't help.
A case is open at salesforce's support.